# Get the width of a TreeViewColumn that would like to be if it were autosized

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

Is there a way to get the width, in pixels, that a `gtk.TreeViewColumn` would want to be if the sizing mode was set as `gtk.TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_AUTOSIZE`, even if it's currently `gtk.TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_FIXED`?

Answer (score 0):

I think [gtk.TreeViewColumn.cell_get_size()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtktreeviewcolumn.html#method-gtktreeviewcolumn--cell-get-size) will do the job.

Sample code:

```
def show_size(treeview):
    col = treeview.get_column(0)
    cell = col.get_cell_renderers()[0]
    size = col.cell_get_position(cell)
    print 'current size: position=%s, width=%s' % size
    size = col.cell_get_size()
    print 'autosize: %s, x=%s, y=%s, w=%s, h=%s' % size
```